# Disjoint sets $A,B$ with $d(A,B) = 0$ in a metric space $M$ compact imply that $\partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let be $A, B$ disjoint sets with $d(A,B) = 0$ in a metric space $M$ compact. Show that $\partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$.

My attempt:

Suppose that $\partial A \cap \partial B = \emptyset$. If $p \in \partial A$, so $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $B(p, \epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $B(p, \epsilon) \cap (M-A) \neq \emptyset$. On the other hand, $p \notin \partial B$, so exists $r > 0$ such that $B(p, r) \subset B$ or $B(p, r) \subset (M-B)$. It's clear that $B(p, r) \subset B$, because $p \in \partial A$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ (this last one by hypothesis), so $d(p,B) > 0$, in particular, exists $b \in B$ such that $d(p,b) > 0$, therefore, $d(p,b) \leq d(p,a) + d(a,b)$, $\forall a \in A$ and $\forall b \in B$, because $p \in \partial A$ and $d(A, B) = 0$, $d(p,b) \leq d(p,a) + d(a,b) < \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, so, taking the limit when $n \longrightarrow \infty$, we have $d(p,b) \leq d(p,a) + d(a,b) < 0$, so $d(p,b) < 0, \forall a \in A, \forall b \in B$, but $d(p,b) > 0$ for some $b \in B$ and here we have a contradiction, so $p \in \partial A \cap \partial B$ $\square$.

I know this proof it isn't correct because I didn't use the compactness of the space $M$, but I have no idea how use compactness here. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and most basic error in your proof is that you don't necessarily know that any element $p\in\partial A$ exists at all.  Even given $p$, you can't necessarily choose $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $d(p,a)<\frac{1}{2n}$ and $d(a,b)<\frac{1}{2n}$ (you can choose $a$ such that $d(p,a)<\frac{1}{2n}$, and you can choose a different $a'$ and $b$ such that $d(a',b)<\frac{1}{2n}$, but there's no reason you can choose $a'$ to be the same as $a$).

Here's a hint on how you can use compactness. Since $d(A,B)=0$, you can find sequences $(a_n)$ in $A$ and $(b_n)$ in $B$ such that $d(a_n,b_n)<1/n$ for all $n$.  Use compactness to show you can assume these sequences both converge, and then think about what you can say about their limits.

Comment: I think that if I'm able to find sequences $(a_n)$ in $A$ and $(b_n)$ in $B$ such that $d(a_n,b_n) < \frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. I solved the problem, because $d(A,B) = 0$, in particular, $d(a,B) = 0$ for some $a \in A$ and $d(b,A) = 0$ for some $b \in B$, so $a \in \overline{B}$ and $b \in \overline{A}$ and it's clear that $a \in \partial B$ and $b \in \partial A$, because $A, B$ are disjoint sets, $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, so $d(a,b) \leq d(a,b_n) + d(b_n,a_n) + d(a_n,b)$, because $a \in \overline{B}$ and $b \in \overline{A}$, $d(a,b_n) < \frac{1}{3n}$, $d(a_n,b) < \frac{1}{3n}$

Comment: and $d(a_n,b_n) < \frac{1}{3n}$, so $d(a,b) \leq d(a,b_n) + d(b_n,a_n) + d(a_n,b) < \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{1}{3n} = \frac{1}{n}$, taking the limit when $n \longrightarrow \infty$, we have $d(a,b) < 0$, this means that $a \in \partial A$ $a, b \in B_{\epsilon}(a) \cap B$, is as $a \in \partial B$ too, we have $\partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$. My doubt now it's why you can ensure that $d(a_n,b_n) < \frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: and it isn't clear where I use compactness here.

Comment: Where did you get your elements $a$ and $b$ from?  It is not true that $d(A,B)=0$ means there exists $a\in A$ such that $d(a,B)=0$ (this can fail if $A$ and $B$ are not compact).

Comment: You are right, sorry, so my proof it isn't correct. I'll try again. By definition,  $d(A,B) = \inf \{ d(a,b); a \in A, b \in B \}$ and, by definition of infimum, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, exists $a_n \in A$ and $b_n \in B$ such that $d(A,B) < d(a_n,b_n) < d(A,B) + \epsilon$. In this case, we have $d(A,B) = 0$ and as epsilon was taken arbitrarily, we can express $\epsilon = \epsilon (n) = \frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, therefore $0 < d(a_n,b_n) < \frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Supposing that $M$ is compact, we have that $a_n \longrightarrow a$ and $b_n \longrightarrow b$, taking the limit when $n \longrightarrow \infty$,  $d(a_n,b_n) \longrightarrow d(a,b)$ because the function distance is continuous.

It's that I think at the moment, is it correct until here?

Comment: Well, you don't automatically know that $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge.  But you know you can choose subsequences of them that do converge.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Supposing that M is compact, we have for sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ subsequences $(a_n)_j$ and $(b_n)_j$ such that $(a_n)_j \longrightarrow a$ and $(b_n)_j \longrightarrow b$, respectively, taking the the limit when $n \longrightarrow \infty$, $d((a_n)_j,(b_n)_j) \longrightarrow d(a,b)$ because the function distance is continuous. Furthermore, $d(a,b) \longrightarrow 0$ taking the the limit when $j \longrightarrow \infty$, because $0 < d(a_n,b_n) < \frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, but how it helps me to prove that exists $p \in \partial A \cap \partial B$?

Comment: Well, you have $d(a,b)=0$ so $a=b$.  Now show $a=b\in \partial A\cap \partial B$.

Comment: I thought this, but I thought that I didn't conclude this because $d(a_n,b_n) > 0$ and $d(a_n,b_n) \longrightarrow d(a,b)$, so $d(a,b) > 0$

Comment: Limits don't preserve strict inequalities.  For instance, $1/n$ converges to $0$ even though $1/n>0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ah, I understood, thank you! Now $a \in \partial A \cap \partial B$, because $a$ is limit of a subsequence $(a_n)_j \subset A$ and is limit of a subsequence $(b_n)_j \subset B$, so every open ball with center in $a$ contain infinitely many point of $A$ and $B$, so every open ball with center in $a$ intersects $A$ and $B$. As $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets, follow that every open ball with center in $a$ intersects $A$. $M - A$, $B$ and $M - B$, so $a \in \partial A \cap \partial B$